# Difference between Touchables from react-native and react-native-gesture-handler

Tags: javascript, react-native

Both of `react-native` and `react-native-gesture-handler` provide Touchables (`TouchableOpacity`, `TouchableHighlight`, etc).

What is the difference between the Touchables from both packages?
Any detailed explanation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the description on their docs is very useful:

> Gesture Handler library provides an implementation of RN's touchable
> components that are based on native buttons and does not rely on JS
> responder system utilized by RN. Our touchable implementation follows
> the same API and aims to be a drop-in replacement for touchables
> available in React Native.
>
> The motivation for using RNGH touchables as a replacement for these
> imported from React Native is to follow built-in native behavior more
> closely by utilizing platform native touch system instead of relying
> on the JS responder system. These touchables and their feedback
> behavior are deeply integrated with native gesture ecosystem and could
> be connected with other native components (e.g. ScrollView) and
> Gesture Handlers easily and in a more predictable way, which follows
> native apps' behavior.

https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/component-touchables

So if you are on the native side (not web) it's better to use Touchables from RNGH. Maybe they will include the new pressable component from RN soon.

Answer (score 6):

One key difference between React Native Gesture Handler's Touchables vs the React Native versions is that React Native Gesture Handler's Touchables do not nest correctly.  So if you have a "card" that has actions but also a touch anywhere else for default behaviour. You will get into issues.

One advantage of RNGH is ther TapGesture allow for better detection of scrolling through "cards" so it does not trigger animations while swiping.   `Pressable` classifies this as `unstable_pressDelay` and is not available in Expo as of SDK 42.

In addition the API between React Native Gesture Handler vs the Touchables are not 1:1.  There's a few nuances that are only highlighted when you're using TypeScript.

So for better future proofing, it's actually better to stick with React Native's `Pressable` API for typical behaviours.  However, if you need some specific low level control or non-standard gestures like swiping then use RNGH.

Comment: agree, RNGH Touchables are often problematic, e.g. they currently don't support hitSlop, testId/accessibilityLabel, and sometimes there are weird bugs with complex nesting, although in simple cases "disallowInterruption" prop can solve some issues. Their "Touchable*" also come with an extra View container that you have to style separately with "containerStyle". 

I wish we could just use Pressable everywhere, but then there is no way to stop propagation from it when you use GestureDetector from RNGH

Comment: @Archimedes Trajano. And you are so right!!! oh...my... I had this issue. I had imported: import { TouchableOpacity } from "react-native-gesture-handler"; and I had a icon on the card. But every time I clicked on the icon I was redirect with navigat to a other screen. What was not correct. Because I had to stay on the same screen. So I imported:  import { TouchableOpacity } from "react-native"; and everything worked correct.

Answer (score 2):

In a practical example, TouchableOpacity from RNGH can be used in a loop and we will be able to identify each object in a loop uniquely(for eg:to get keyId of an element in a loop) but we use the other touchableOpacity from react-native this cant be done

> in this code snippet each time slot card can be uniquly identified and everytime selected function is called it will be populated by a different value(this touchableOpacity is imported from RNGC)

```
<FlatGrid
      itemDimension={80}
      data={timeslots}
      spacing={8}
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <View >
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{selected(item);}}>
        <TimeslotCard name={item.slot} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        </View> )}
/>
```

Comment: This is a somewhat misleading or at least incomplete answer. Why would the same not be achievable with RN's `TouchableOpacity`?