# Error: NativeViewGestureHandler must be used as a descendant of GestureHandlerRootView

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I've installed **GestureHandler** (`npx expo install react-native-gesture-handler`) and also imported it into my ***App.tsx*** file on line 3 with polyfills

`import 'react-native-gesture-handler';`

was doing it by the [Expo Docs](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/v48.0.0/sdk/gesture-handler/) and for some reason it still doesn't seem to be working even after running `npx expo start --clear` (to clear cache) it will gives me this error:

```
Error: NativeViewGestureHandler must be used as a descendant of GestureHandlerRootView.
Otherwise the gestures will not be recognized.
See https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/installation for more details.
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Okay so turned out I am dumb and I imported `TouchableOpacity` from **react-native-gesture-handler** instead of **react-native**  sorry but maybe might help someone so just posting the solution here :) happy coding

Comment: I did the same with `TouchableWithoutFeedback`. Importing it from `react-native-gesture-handler` was causing the issue 

Comment: I totally did the same and you saved me. Thanks for not just commenting "nevermind, it is solved"

Answer (score 16):

It looks like this was a recent change by the team behind `react-native-gesture-handler`. A GitHub issue was opened recently and has been resolved by this comment: https://github.com/gorhom/react-native-bottom-sheet/issues/1373#issuecomment-1550661599

"I fixed this by adding GestureHandlerRootView wrapper at the root of my project (E.g App.tsx). You can find the instruction here [https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/installation/#js"](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/installation/#js%22)

So your code will looks something like this:

```js
<GestureHandlerRootView>
// your code
</GestureHandlerRootView>
```

Comment: yes yes you can have also this solution but overall it's easier to just watch the intellisense more carefuly when clicking on auto-import :D

Comment: TouchableOpacity can be imported from either react-native-gesture-handler or react-native, however they have slightly different behaviors. This SO answer describes the difference well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64742309/16913644, an oversimplification would be that RNGH's touchables are typically better for native development, whereas RN's are better for web

Comment: I needed to define as `<GestureHandlerRootView style={{ flex: 1 }}>`, otherwise my screen went blank.

Answer (score 2):

you might have imported TouchableOpacity or RefreshControl from react-native-gesture-handler, import it from react-native

Answer (score 2):

just need to import "ScrollView" from "react-native" instead of "react-native-gesture-handler"

Answer (score -1):

I have also faced this issue and fixed it by downgrading react-native-gesture-handler to 2.9.0