NativeViewGestureHandler must be used as a descendant of GestureHandlerRootView. Otherwise the gestures will not be recognized
I'm new to React Native and currently working on a simple Todo app. However, I'm encountering an issue related to gestures. Specifically, I'm getting the following error
NativeViewGestureHandler must be used as a descendant of GestureHandlerRootView. Otherwise, the gestures will not be recognized.
Here's the relevant code for my app.
import { useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList } from "react-native";

export default function Index() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([
    { text: 'buy coffee', key: '1' },
    { text: 'create an app', key: '2' },
    { text: 'play cricket', key: '3' },
  ]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.content}>
        <View style={styles.list}>
          <FlatList
            data={todos}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <Text>{item.text}</Text>
            )}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff'
  },
  content: {
    padding: 40
  },
  list: {
    marginTop: 20
  }
});

What I've tried:
I’ve wrapped my root component in GestureHandlerRootView but the error persists.
I’ve made sure to install and link react-native-gesture-handler correctly.
What am I missing? How can I fix this error and integrate gesture handlers properly in my app?

The NativeViewGestureHandler requires the component to be wrapped inside GestureHandlerRootView. This is a common requirement when using the react-native-gesture-handler library
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList } from "react-native";
import { GestureHandlerRootView } from "react-native-gesture-handler"; // Import GestureHandlerRootView

export default function Index() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([
    { text: 'buy coffee', key: '1' },
    { text: 'create an app', key: '2' },
    { text: 'play cricket', key: '3' },
  ]);

  return (
    <GestureHandlerRootView style={styles.container}> {/* Wrap your component here */}
      <View style={styles.content}>
        <View style={styles.list}>
          <FlatList
            data={todos}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <Text>{item.text}</Text>
            )}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    </GestureHandlerRootView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff'
  },
  content: {
    padding: 40
  },
  list: {
    marginTop: 20
  }
});


Thank you for your suggestion! I wrapped my component inside a GestureHandlerRootView as you mentioned, but unfortunately, the issue still persists.

The above code is correct and works properly; thus, you must check the index.js and app.js bcz they are the entry point where you call your app navigation. It is possible that the GestureHandlerRootView has been added to allow the app to access the gesture handler.
Additionally you can visit this sites where you get more information that will help resolve your problem.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76957042/error-nativeviewgesturehandler-must-be-used-as-a-descendant-of-gesturehandlerro
https://github.com/gorhom/react-native-bottom-sheet/issues/1373#issuecomment-1550661599
